# Finding balanced number of samples

Tags: python, machine-learning, annotation-processing

I have a annotation dataset consisting of multiple text files in a folder. I have more than 100000 text samples. The folder structure looks like this

```
annotation/
   ....Sample0.txt
   ....Sample1.txt
   ....Sample2.txt
   ....
   ....
   ....Sample100000.txt
```

Each text file looks like this below:

```
cat 0.00 0 0.00 50 33 44 45 
dog 0.00 0 0.00 60 10 82 98
beer 0.00 0 0.00 90 50 49 52
```

The fist word in each file contain classes.

I have written a script which gives the class count of each classes by mentioning a percentage of files.

```
import glob
from collections import Counter

path = 'annotations/'
files = glob.glob(f'{path}*.txt')

words =[]
filePerc = len(files)*80//100 # get only 80% of data from the folder
for i in range(filePerc):
    f = open(files[i],'r')
    for line in f:
        words.append(line.split()[0])
        class_count = Counter(words)
    
   
    print("Number of samples :",filePerc)
    print("Class :",class_count)
```

This gives me output like this below - eg:

```
Number of samples :100
Class : Counter({'cat': 40, 'dog': 14, 'beer': 5, 'lion':25, 'deer':16})
```

However the class is not properly distributed.

What I am trying to achieve is, I want to select  ****N%****  samples from the dataset and those **N%** portion should have balanced number of samples per class. But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You mention ' the class is not properly distributed'.  What is meant by this?  What is the class distribution across all the files?

Comment: Suppose if there are 50000 samples in total, if I want 25% portion of the total and if suppose the 25% is 10000 samples then I want the class to distributed like               {'cat': 2486, 'dog': 2486, 'beer': 2486, 'lion': 1001, 'deer': 2486}  @DarrylG